# Can i use shape for border and background color in same xml?

Tags: android, xml, shapes

i want to use the shape xml for show border on my listview items. Also, i want to set the background color in this xml. How can i do it? I have the next code for the border but i don´t know where set the background color.

```
<shape  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <solid android:color="#FFFFFF" />

        <stroke
            android:width="3dip"
            android:color="#B1BCBE" />

        <corners android:radius="10dip" />

        <padding
            android:bottom="0dip"
            android:left="0dip"
            android:right="0dip"
            android:top="0dip" /></shape>
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: <solid android:color="#FFFFFF" />
this is your background color

Comment: Yes you can use, but you already done it.

Answer (score 2):

Change Color code in your `Drawable`

```
<solid android:color="#FFFFFF" />// Change color code
```

> **solid**:: A solid color to fill the shape.

Please take a look at [Official docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#Shape)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle" >

<corners android:radius="5dp" />

<stroke
    android:width="3dip"
    android:color="#B1BCBE" />

<solid android:color="#323232" />// Background colour 

<padding
    android:bottom="0dip"
    android:left="0dip"
    android:right="0dip"
    android:top="0dip" />

</shape>
```